# Recently many "scratch tracks" of Michael Jackson acapella posted to YouTube - any particular reason why?

Tags: recording, release, michael-jackson

About ten days ago the YouTube channel [SuperflySister @YourMusicArchive607](https://www.youtube.com/@YourMusicArchive607/about) posted a dozen or more "scratch tracks" of Michael Jackson singing acapella. According to a comment under [one of them](https://youtu.be/D4roYL3J2AM):

> If you don't know, a "scratch track" is a throwaway, used as a demonstration to teach the band a new song.

**Question:** Is there anything that happened recently that made this suddenly possible now, or was this just at the discretion of the channel owner?

---

Another example: [Michael Jackson - Thriller (Acapella) (Scratch Vocal - w/Rod Temperton Bar Counts) (Studio Quality)](https://youtu.be/cT454b3HaEQ)

Answer (score 1):

The definition of 'scratch track' is correct, but the channel posting these is mis-using the term. Basically what they've posted is simply the single vocal [LVox] channel from a set of leaked multitracks.

It happens; someone with access to the multitracks - brought out of storage for a remaster or remix project - steals a copy. This then escapes onto the interweb at large. A lot of multitracks leaked during the process to create the stems for Guitar Hero & similar projects.

Sometimes this kind of thing is taken down within days, sometimes they stay forever. It's often hard to tell whether someone took the time to license it correctly or just thought they could get away with it.